# short circuit an alkaline battery

Tags: electric-circuits, explosions, batteries

i'm not doing anything related to physics, but i'm just curious : What really happen when i short circuit an alkaline battery ? some article in the net shown that fire/explosion can be happened when short circuit the battery. How can this happen? coz i got some article said that there is an 'internal' resistance of the battery that prevent very high current is drawn (exceed the maximum current), so i think this become the safety tool , so current or temperature won't be a problem.

But why can still produce fire or explosion ? And why the manufacture of the battery (like for example some of AA alkaline) doesn't provide info about maximum c rating or maximum current to be drawn (so where can i find it?). Ussually only Voltage and capacity(mAH) is printed. Is that kind of info is not important so it's ignored. Sometime the mAH is not even printed on AA batery. I can only see it on lipo or nimh batt.

Thanx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just sacrificed an AA manganese alkaline battery to the cause of physics.

When I first shorted the battery it produced a current of about 9.5 amps, which I thought was actually pretty impressive. However over the course of 30 seconds the current dropped to around 5 amps. The battery got pretty warm, though I don't think it would have set fire to anything and it didn't explode. The power generated was around 7.5 watts, so it isn't huge, though the power is concentrated in a fairly small area.

I'd be careful about doing this to a bigger battery. Larger batteries will have a lower internal resistance, and given how much current an AA battery produces I can well believe you could heat a bigger battery to the point where it becomes dangerous.

I'vd be very very careful about trying this with batteries that have a particularly low internal resistance like lead-acid or nickel-cadmium batteries!

Comment: Hi John, thanx for doing that experiment, that's very kind of you. I was afraid doing that coz i don't want the batt to burst into my face lol. So the alkaline AA 1.5V battery won't actually explode :-),  i won't try it with bigger battery (or my rc car -lippo battery) for sure.

Comment: I checked the battery manufacturers web site first, and that assured me that an AA battery was very unlikely to explode. Still, I stood well back while I was doing it :-)

Comment: I've set stuff on fire by accidentally shorting a D cell NiCd. Yikes!

Comment: @dmckee: I'm part of a robotics team of my institute (for ASME SDC 2013). Now, we use Lithium polymer batteries. Short these, and they explode. No intermediate fire stage, just _boom_. And we have some rather large LiPo batteries in the lab which we use regularly. I've seen a large lead acid battery catch fire, but I've never been (mis)fortunate enough to see a LiPo exploding :S

Comment: I did a similar test with a Zinc-Carbon battery: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76220/what-to-expect-by-short-circuiting-a-zinc-carbon-aa-battery/76226#76226

What I did _not_ monitored was the flow of current, because I was afraid it could blow my meter. @JohnRennie How did you measured that 9.5 amps? Did you use a normal multimeter? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks, mine are up to 10 so I'd better not use them to test max amp of a shorted Zinc-Carbon AA cell. Although I am very curious to see how they compare :P. Next multimeter.

Comment: @JohnRennie I ended up testing (by using an external fuse first) and I realized that Zinc-Carbon deliver far less current when shorted. Something about 2.5A (one meter read something less, another slightly above that).

Comment: @alan: when you short a battery the current is limited by the internal resistance. The internal resistance depends on the battery size and the ambient temperature, but as a rough guide a small zinc-carbon cell wil have an internal resistance of about $0.5\Omega$ while a similar manganese alkaline battery will have an internal resistance of about $0.15\Omega$. So the manganese alkaline battery will produce three to four times as much current when short circuited. I believe nickel-cadium batteries have an even lower internal resistance.

Comment: One of my students works for a specialty battery manufacturer in town and brought us a video of a nail penetration test (that is, they clamp the cell down and shove a nail through the cell with a hydraulic system...) conducted on a LiPo cell. The spray of white-hot fiery stuff was about 2 meters long. Wow!