# Question re Simple Electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism

I was interested in building a simple electromagnet for the kids - and many tutorials online suggest just looping a wire around a nail as pictured below.  But how is this safe ?  Isn't this essentially an electrical short directly across the battery ?  (You wouldn't take a wire and directly short it across a battery.) Why would coiling wire around a nail make this any different ?

[image]

Comment: you need wire covered with insulation.

Comment: Okay, but even with insulation isn't it damaging on the battery ?  The reason I ask is that I actually want to use a lab power supply as the power source - but don't fancy shorting across the terminals (and damaging my power supply).  Should I add a ceramic resistor ?  Or is there some property of twisting the wire like this which creates extra resistance whilst under load ?

Comment: @PatrickRynhart : As I noted in my answer, shorting an ordinary battery, such as AA, is probably OK, but don't do that with your power supply - the voltage there can be higher and you don't know its internal resistance.

Comment: Thanks @akhmeteli.  If I limited the output voltage of my power supply to around 9V or so, and added a 1-2 Ohm resistor in series would this be safe enough ?  (I did a quick google search to find that the internal resistance of a 9V battery is approximately this value.)

Comment: I guess it's also dependent on the current.... My lab power supply allows current limits to be specified though

Comment: @PatrickRynhart the wire has resistance which can be measured. Voltage is known; Ohm’s law is also known. Calculate the current.

Comment: A current-limited power supply is good, but it won't hurt to give it some assistance with a small resistor. And put lots of turns on your electromagnet. I assume you'll be holding this electromagnet in your bare hands, so you'll be able to feel how warm it is. ;)

Comment: Thanks.  And yes, I know this is simple electronics.  But I just get a bit nervous putting an electrical short across my lab power supply :) ....

Comment: Probably a good idea to put a nice chunky capacitor across your power supply too. When you disconnect the power from the electromagnet you can get a substantial spike of back EMF.

Comment: @PatrickRynhart : Look, I am not comfortable with giving such safety-related advice. In my answer I relied on the results of a specific "experiment" performed by others and warned you about fire hazard.

Comment: It's alright - I'm not going to do it right now.  It's something that can wait weeks, e.g.  Just trying to understand the best way to go about doing it safely. Thank you @PM2Ring for suggesting the capacitor.

Comment: If you haven't played with a home-made electromagnet before (or not for a long time), I suggest you try it with a simple battery first. And use an old-fashioned cheap carbon-zinc cell, not an alkaline. And *definitely* not a lithium!

Comment: Perfect thank you for the advice - I will start with a 6V "brick" torch battery.  (An old school one, i.e. not Alkaline / Lithium.)

Answer (score 0):

If you short a battery, probably nothing spectacular will happen (see [short circuit an alkaline battery](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30594/short-circuit-an-alkaline-battery) ), although you should beware of fire hazard. The battery has internal resistance that limits the current.